# How to send port address and value to usb-parallel adapter?

Tags: .net, usb

I have a DOS program on an old PC that is used to adjust the coil current on an old analytical device.  The DOS program sends data to the old PC's parallel port (LPT1) via the OUT command: **OUT &H278, &H2**, for example.

I would like to port this program to .NET, run it on a new PC, and eliminate the old PC.  The new PC does not have a parallel port.  I have a USB to DB25 adapter cable.  How can I reproduce the same functionality of the OUT command through the USB-DB25 adapter using .NET?

Here's info on the BASIC OUT command:
http://spriteshack.com/?p=996

Comment: You will probably want to use the [SerialPort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.aspx) class.

Comment: You could purchase and install an "add-on" parallel port - one that fits into a pci-e slot.

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=pci-e+parallel